# zapier - IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'products.cvs'

Tags: python, zapier

For those of you that know Zapier, I am making a zap using Python that will trigger the code below every month. The code extract products from my website that uses shopify and returns the values in a .csv file. The code works fine in the command prompt, but I get the error above in Zapier. Does anyone know how to fix the error? Please refer to the line below where the error is coming from:

with open('products.csv', 'w') as f:

```
import csv
import json
import urllib2
import sys

url = 'https://blahblah.com'

def get_page(page):
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url + '?page={}'.format(page)).read()
    products = json.loads(data)['products']
    return products

with open('products.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Category', 'Name', 'Price', 'Vendor'])
    page = 1
    products = get_page(page)
    while products:
        for product in products:
            name = product['title']
            category = product['product_type']
            vendor = product['vendor']
            for variant in product['variants']:
                price = variant['price']
                row = [category, name, price, vendor]
                row = [uni.encode('utf8') for uni in row]
                writer.writerow(row)
        page += 1
        products = get_page(page)
```

Comment: It appears that the file is read-only, probably due to security features on Zapier's end. Why do you need to use Zapier to handle this though? It doesn't look like you're passing this data to another service in any way. Why can't you just handle this locally or on a server?

Comment: @LaneTerry I was told Zapier was a good approach. Could you point me in the right direction if I want to handle this locally or on a server? I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Just run this code on a PC with Python installed if you only need the CSV.