# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system when trying to open PDF in Python Code by Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I am creating a zap in Zapier that searches for a particular client and then finds their folder in Google Drive. It then takes a PDF document from the Google Drive folder and uploads to HelloSign to send to the client. I am using a Code by Zapier step to pull the PDF from Google Drive and upload to HelloSign.

The code I have in the Code by Zapier step works on my local machine, but when I attempt to run it in Zapier I get "OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system" for the document I'm trying to create so I can read the PDF for the line that has "with open('Test.pdf','wb') as f". From reading [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196950/zapier-ioerror-errno-30-read-only-file-system-products-cvs#comment89375844_51196950), it sounds like this is caused by Zapier permissions not allowing the creation of files on their system. The code block that is erroring is pretty straightforward.

```
output = {'status_code' : ''}

key = 'xxxxxxxx'

url = 'https://' + key + ':@api.hellosign.com/v3/signature_request/send'

response = requests.get(input['pdf'])
with open('Test.pdf','wb') as f:
    pdf = f.write(response.content)

files = {
    'Doc' : pdf
}

param = {
    'test_mode' : 1,
    'title' : "Test from HelloSign",
    'subject' : "Doc Ready",
    'message' : 'Hi! Please sign the attached doc.',
    'signing_redirect_url' : 'https://www.google.com/',
    'signers[0][name]' : input['name'],
    'signers[0][email_address]' : input['email']
    }

r = requests.post(url=url,files = files, params=param)

output['status_code'] = r.status_code
```

What alternatives do I have to read the PDF without using open() so I can pass along the PDF to HelloSign to send off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
output = {'status_code' : ''}

key = 'xxxxxxxx'

url = 'https://' + key + ':@api.hellosign.com/v3/signature_request/send'

response = requests.get(input['pdf'])

files = {
    'file' : response.content
}

param = {
    'test_mode' : 1,
    'title' : "Test from HelloSign",
    'subject' : "Doc Ready",
    'message' : 'Hi! Please sign the attached doc.',
    'signing_redirect_url' : 'https://www.google.com/',
    'signers[0][name]' : input['name'],
    'signers[0][email_address]' : input['email']
    }

r = requests.post(url=url,files = files, params=param)

output['status_code'] = r.status_code
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I guess I didn't need to actually open the document to send it to the next service.